# Going from 32-bit to 64-bit, will "Reinstall Ubuntu" in the installer break my system?

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, 64-bit, 32-bit

I'm trying to go from a 32-bit Xubuntu 14.04 to a 64-bit Xubuntu 14.04. In the installer, I get this option:

[image: Installer screenshot]

Reinstall Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

My /home is already on a separate partition, so my documents are all safe. What I'm wondering about here is the "installed software will be kept" bit. Does this mean it just doesn't touch my already installed software? But the installed programs are all 32-bit packages! Wouldn't my freshly installed 64-bit system break right away?

Well, what I really want to know is: does the installer properly handle this? For all I know it just gets a record of the installed software and then installs the appropriate 64-bit packages over them, but as it is, I just can't be certain what it will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not

"installed software will be kept"

It is

"installed software will be kept where possible"

The installer will see a difference in architecture and come to the conclusion "where possible" is not applicable and delete all 32-bit software before installing the 64-bit version.

The only thing I am not sure about are config files. These might remain on your system. I doubt config files will mess things up.

When switching architecture I would suggest picking the more sensible option: format+re-install (option 2).

Comment: Thank you. In the end I've opted for going "Something else", where I formatted / and reused my old /home since it has too much data I want to keep and can't back up anywhere else.